# How to model a "grid" in a database?

Tags: database, database-design

I am building a questionnarie for my website, and i want one of the answer types to look like this:

```
[Question] How much did you like the food in:

[Answer]
        1    2    3    4    5
2006   [ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [x]  [ ]
2008   [ ]  [ ]  [x]  [ ]  [ ]
2010   [ ]  [ ]  [ ]  [x]  [ ]
2012   [ ]  [x]  [ ]  [ ]  [ ]

[Button] Save
```

the [] tags are supposed to be radiobuttons, and each year should be 1 radiobutton group.

I need to build a component, so that a user can define how many columns and rows the answer for his/her question should have. Also the user should be able to specify the text for each row and column.

How do i model this in the database, and bind the question with the answer? How do i save the answer as 1 answer?

Currently what i have made looks like this:

```
[Table]Question

id (int)
question_wording (text)
question_number (varchar(50))
visible (int)


[Table]Multiple_Choice_Question
id (int)
choice_woring (varchar(200))
choice_number (varchar(50))
```

And then i have a cross reference table to bind the question with multiple answer possibilites. With this solution, i would have to create a question for every year, like:

```
How much did you like the food in 2006?
How much did you like the food in 2008?
```

And bind this to the answer possibilites with the question through the cross reference table.

Also the answer table looks like this:

```
[Table]Answer
id (int)
question_number (FK)
choice_number (FK)
```

Here is a picture to illustrate the grid:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/857/capturedu.jpg/

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hmm.. I don't think Relational model is powerful enough to represent this with simplicity. One option is to model the answer/questions options as a JSON object and stored this JSON in a single column in database

Comment: @Ankur: the relational model is indeed powerful enough to represent this with simplicity; it cannot represent the data, however, unless they are first simplified into non-complex single-values.

Comment: If you store the multi-values as a JSON-encoded object, the data might become unusable, or usable only in certain databases that know how to parse arbitrarily-structured objects that have been so encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the requirement "save the answer as 1 answer?". In a relational model this would be stored as multiple rows. Here's a basic data definition:

Since different grids must be possible I suggest the definition of rows and columns:

```
ROW_DEFINITIONS
- ID
- FORM_ID       - which form are we defining
- FIELD_NUMBER  - which field on the form is this
- ROW_NUMBER    - the row number of the grid
- DESCRIPTION   - the description of the row

COLUMN_DEFINITIONS
- ID
- FORM_ID
- FIELD_NUMBER
- COLUMN_NUMBER - the column number of the grid
- DESCRIPTION   - the description of the column
```

Then to register the answers:

```
ANSWERS
- ID
- FORM_ID       - for which form is this answer
- USER          - who gave this answer
- ROW_NUMBER    - the row of the given answer
- COLUMN_NUMBER - the column of the given answer
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am binding to a Question entity and not a FORM_ID. How can i reuse the rows and columns, because as far as i can see i would have to write all rows and columns again for different questions?

Comment: @Nanek: The "Question entity" is a complex (i.e. non-monadic) thing that can be represented in a relational database only by several interrelated tables, and you're complicating that even further by having multi-part questions. If you want your data to be subjected to statistical analysis, the data must be representable in grid (row/column) form where each cell contains ONLY ONE VALUE. You have to learn the fundamentals of relational design. No pain no gain.

Comment: @Tim Thanks, but the "Question entity" i am talking about is in this threads question. It can be represented in 1 table.

Comment: @Nanek: since your question is about database design, I tried to represent the information in a relation database format. If you already have a model that represents all entities at runtime please explain. That might help us understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

> "How do I save the answer as 1
>   answer?"

A value in a typical relational database is monadic, not multi-valued, and in your example the answer has several values corresponding to each year.  You have two options to track data for these question*s* (plural, not this question, singular):

```
      How did you like the food in
          2006
          2008
          2010
          2012
```

1) Each year corresponds to a column. Adding new years requires adding new columns to the table.

or

2) Each year's answer corresponds to a child record in a separate ANSWERS table:

```
        QUESTION table (questionid, questiontext)
        ANSWERS table (id, questionid, answervalue)
```

where there can be one or more answers in the ANSWERS table to a single question in the QUESTIONS table-- like line-item entries on an Order. A second table in a many-to-one relation with the first is how a "normalized" relational database structures such data.

The table definitions above are bare-bones and simplistic. If I were going to track multi-part questions, I'd probably have a QUESTIONPARTS table which relates back to QUESTIONS, and relate my ANSWERS table back to QUESTIONPARTS, or use the first approach where each part of a multi-part question is treated as a separate question which has its own column.

Presentation-layer issues (GUI) ought have nothing to do with data structure.  *The data must ultimately be usable/queryable* and the visual component you design to gather the information does not determine the underlying data structure.

You must make sure that the data are usable, otherwise the exercise of gathering the data is a waste of time for everyone.

P.S. In  recent years, object-orientation (support for custom user-defined structures) has been grafted onto relational databases. The two major commercial players, Oracle and SQL Server, now support this but these are proprietary extensions to the SQL standard and are not portable from one system to another. And for many years before that, databases like PICK and its variants have supported multi-values. The multiple values in a column were separated from each other using specific delimiters. This was often called the "nested relational" model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Would it be possible for you to provide a concrete example on how to implement solution #2? Ultimately i need to run statistics on the data gathered, so as long as i can find out which answers were given to which question it would be great.

Comment: A concrete example would require a specific database & GUI, whereas you've tagged the question generically.  In a SQL-standards compliant database, you would define the necessary tables: QUESTIONS, QUESTIONPARTS, ANSWERS with the appropriate foreign key constraints; then you would have to write the code to select from and update the relevant rows/columns in the database. You would need to have knowledge of SQL, of some middleware, and of how to bind data to your specific GUI components, whether that be an HTML table, a java widget, or a .NET WinForms control. Begin with FOREIGN KEYS and SQL.

Comment: If you want to give your users the ability to define the possible choices for each question/each part of a multi-part question, you need yet another table, QUESTIONPARTCHOICES, which relates back to QUESTIONPART; that table contains the set of displayed choices for each question-part, and the corresponding value that should be stored in the database when the user selects one of those choices.

Comment: What i meant was a concrete example of the database implementation :P I use ASP.NET MVC 3 with Entity Framework 4.0